# nioNeoDbPersistence turned null

Tags: neo4j, shutdown

I am using neo4j as a backend, I started to have a weird error (see below). After looking up on neo4j@googlegouprs.com I figured out that may be I'm trying to use a DB that has been shutdown. Since I'm pretty sure that my code is not executing any shutdown() instruction I just disabled the shutdownHook(), yet, nothing happens. Someone please has an idea about what is happening or (and) a clue how to solve it.

Thank you in advance

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NioNeoDbPersistenceSource.createReadOnlyResourceConnection(NioNeoDbPersistenceSource.java:96) 
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getReadOnlyResource(PersistenceManager.java:222) 
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getReadOnlyResourceIfPossible(PersistenceManager.java:245) 
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.loadLightNode(PersistenceManager.java:73) 
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getNodeByIdOrNull(NodeManager.java:308)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getNodeById(NodeManager.java:325) 
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.getNodeById(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:912)
```

Comment: provide some more details, code snippet, which Neo4j version.

Comment: I am using Neo4j entreprise version 1.9M. I am afraid that the code is a little bit too big :). But I can describe the context. I exported a big xmi file to neo4j DB and I am using the embedded server to query this model. The thing is that when the resource is more or less big  (10000 node) neo4j fail (sometimes) to get a node by it's ID, with a little bit of debugging I figured out that the attriutes values of nioNeoDbPersistenceSource are null. If I repeat the debugging for three or four times it works. With small resources it works as well. I hope these information might be of help :)

Comment: Why are you using a ReadOnly database? Can you try just a normal EmbeddedGraphDatabase?